# Why do I need to explicitly include a gem when it's already a dependency of another gem I'm using?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, dependency-management

I have created a gem/Rails engine (let's call it **my_rails_gem**) that depends on another gem; specifically, the [**composite_primary_keys**](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys) gem (some of the models need it).  So in the .gemspec file, I have

```ruby
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  #...
  s.add_dependency 'composite_primary_keys'
```

The problem is that when I include the **my_rails_gem** in another Rails project's Gemfile and try to use the models, I get errors about **composite_primary_keys**' functionality.  I must also explicitly add `gem 'composite_primary_keys'` to the app's Gemfile for it to function correctly.

Why is this?  Isn't this the whole point of Bundle and gem dependencies?  I want to take the burden off the developer using **my_rails_gem** to remember to have to include **composite_primary_keys**, but this is specifically preventing that.  Am I doing something wrong, or are my expectations/understanding wrong?

Comment: How are you consuming it in your application? Do you `require` it anywhere, manually or via an autoloading mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason that the dependent gem is not automatically required is so that the user of your gem (you) have the option of requiring the dependent gem. There are reasons for that, but it's a bit of a longer conversation.

If you want the dependent gem to be required automatically when you include your gem, then in your `my_rails_gem.rb` file (in your `lib` directory) you can do:

```
require 'composite_primary_keys'
```

I believe that ought to do the trick for you. At least, that's how I do it.

Also, if the dependent gem has stylesheet and javascript assets that you want to include (I suspect `composite_primary_keys` does not), you'll need to add the appropriate directives to your `my_rails_gem.js` and `my_rails_gem.sass` (or whatever templating engine you use) files.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.